# What does Scope do in GoogleApiClient?

Tags: android, google-api, android-googleapiclient

Can any one explain me what is this `addScope(Scope scope)` method does in **GoogleApiClient**.

```
new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
.addConnectionCallbacks(this)
.addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
.addApi(Plus.API)
.addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)// what really does this?
.build();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scope defines the permissions you need to do what you need to do.

If you application needs to read from a users google drive account then you would request *https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly* which grants you  "`read-only access to file metadata and file content`"  however if you need to be able to upload to google drive you may want to ask for *https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive*   which grants  `"Full, permissive scope to access all of a user's files."`

Scope defines the scope of access an application is granted.

The scope in question [Plus.login](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth#authorization-scopes) https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login

> This is the recommended login scope providing access to social
>   features. This scope implicitly includes the profile scope and also
>   requests that your app be given access to: 
>  * the age range of the
>   authenticated user 
>   * the list of circled people that the user has
>   granted your app access to know 
>   * the methods for reading, writing and
>   deleting app activities (moments) to Google on behalf of the user 
>  In
>   addition, this scope enables cross-platform single sign-on.

Answer (score 0):

> Scopes are strings that enable access to particular resources, such as
>   user data.

Please see the [doc](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth#authorization-scopes) and [scopes summary](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/Scopes#constant-summary).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10400941)

Comment: @MrEngineer13 thanks! I will keep this in my mind in the future.